# NTVDM System Error 4001h when running a 32-bit DOS app

Tags: assembly, x86-emulation, ntvdm

I have cross-compiled a 32-bit analog clock made in [ArithmeticExpressionCompiler](https://flatassembler.github.io/compiler.html) from Linux to DOS using the GNU Assembler. When run under FreeDOS in QEMU or VirtualBox (which are far better emulators than NTVDM is, right?), it creates this picture:
[image]
I expected it to also run on Windows 10. However, when I try to run it on Windows 10, I get this error:
[image]
What does that even mean? My program is not 16-bit, it's 32-bit, so why is some 16-bit subsystem even being run? And what does the "error 4001h" mean? Windows is supposed to be able to run 32-bit DOS programs, right?
Here is the source code for my program, sorry if it's a bit long, but I have no idea what might be causing this error (my knowledge of system programming is minimal):

```
Syntax GAS
;This is the same program as in the "analogClock.aec" file, just modified to
;run on DOS instead of Linux. It also compiles using GNU Assembler.
;Namely, GCC 9.3.0 and GNU Assembler 2.34, although they are released in
;2019, still feature the ability to compile for DOS. You don't need to 
;run them on DOS for that, in fact, I doubt they even can be run on DOS.
;If you manage to compile them to run on DOS, they will probably run out of 
;RAM even for the simplest programs (DOS can't use more than 64MB of RAM,
;which is far too little to run a modern compiler). You can run them on
;Linux and they will produce a DOS executable which you then can run in an
;emulator. That's called cross-compiling. Now, it's not possible to do with
;the stripped-down version of GNU Compiler Collection (GCC) you get with
;Linux, you need to build it from source to get all the features (among 
;other things, cross-compilation to many OS-es). It's not too hard, but it
;does take hours to compile full version of GCC even on a super-modern
;computer. For some reason that escapes me, this particular executable
;causes DosBox to crash, even though it works on FreeDOS in VirtualBox.
;Now, I hope this goes without saying, but if some modern program runs on 
;DOS, that's probably a coincidence, and you can't count on it working 
;flawlessly. Developers have long stopped testing whether their app works
;under DOS. So, while the C library that comes with GCC 9.3.0 can compile
;for DOS, attempts to actually link with it lead to countless linker errors.
;GCC will by default attempt to link to the C library, even if your code
;doesn't use any of the functions present in it. So, you need to compile
;the assembly code ArithmeticExpressionCompiler produces with:
;   djgpp-gcc -o analogClockForDOS.exe -ffreestanding -nostdlib analogClockForDOS.s
;For that reason, I wasn't able to compile Duktape to run on DOS.
;Why use GNU Assembler instead of FlatAssembler? Well, first of all, I
;already have tons of inline assembly compatible with GNU Assembler (from
;"analogClock.aec" which runs on Linux). Second, when you work in
;GNU Assembler, you don't have to write the complicated code for putting
;the processor in the 32-bit mode (DOS programs automatically start in
;16-bit mode), GNU Assembler does that for you.
;Now, in order for 32-bit apps to be able to run on DOS, you need to have
;a driver called DPMI (DOS Protected Mode Interface). It comes pre-installed
;in FreeDOS, but not on MS-DOS. It also comes with Windows 3.x.
;FlatAssembler for DOS is also a 32-bit app and it won't run on DOS without
;a DPMI installed and run.
AsmStart ;So, the following code is generated by GCC 9.3.0, plus some inline assembly I put in the C program.
    .file   "analogClock.c"
    .section .text
/APP
    .intel_syntax noprefix
call _main #I hope this goes without saying, but when you are developing...
#...for a system without a C library, there is no guarantee "main" will...
#...be called first (or even at all before your program crashes),
#you need to take care of that yourself.
.att_syntax

/NO_APP
    .globl  _putchar
_putchar:
LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    subl    $4, %esp
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax
    movb    %al, -4(%ebp)
/APP
# 9 "analogClock.c" 1
    movb -4(%ebp),%dl
movb $0x02,%ah
int $0x21

# 0 "" 2
/NO_APP
    nop
    leave
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
LFE0:
    .comm   result,4
    .comm   i,4
    .comm   x,4
    .comm   y,4
    .comm   currentSign,4
    .comm   centerX,4
    .comm   centerY,4
    .comm   distance,4
    .comm   clockRadius,4
    .comm   output,7360
    .comm   hour,4
    .comm   minute,4
    .comm   second,4
    .comm   angle,4
    .comm   endOfTheHandX,4
    .comm   endOfTheHandY,4
    .comm   coefficientOfTheDirection,4
    .comm   windowWidth,4
    .comm   windowHeight,4
    .comm   lowerBoundX,4
    .comm   upperBoundX,4
    .comm   lowerBoundY,4
    .comm   upperBoundY,4
    .comm   isXWithinBounds,4
    .comm   isYWithinBounds,4
    .comm   expectedY,4
    .comm   expectedX,4
    .comm   j,4
    .comm   ASCIIofSpaceAsFloat32,4
    .comm   ASCIIofDigit0AsFloat32,4
    .comm   ASCIIofColonAsFloat32,4
    .comm   ASCIIofNewLineAsFloat32,4
    .globl  _main
_main:
LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    subl    $24, %esp
/APP
# 18 "analogClock.c" 1
.ifdef debugForDOS #When you don't have a good debugger (like when working on DOS), you need to find some clever ways to debug. You know, like printing "Hello world!" step by step.
    .intel_syntax noprefix
    mov dl,'H'
    mov ax,0x200
    int 0x21
.att_syntax
.endif
.intel_syntax noprefix #Get current time. As we have no access to the standard C library here, we need to look up a way to do that in DOS API.
mov ax,0x2C00
int 0x21
mov byte ptr hour,ch
fild dword ptr hour
fstp dword ptr hour
mov byte ptr minute,cl
fild dword ptr minute
fstp dword ptr minute
mov byte ptr second,dh
fild dword ptr second
fstp dword ptr second #Eh, now I understand why some assembly-language programmers prefer att_syntax to intel_syntax (no need to write "dword ptr" there).
#Let's also set the graphic card to text-mode, in case it isn't in it (though I don't know if it's possible to invoke my program from some other mode without crashing DOS before my program even begins then).
mov ax,0x0003
int 0x10
.att_syntax
AsmEnd ;And now finally follows a program written in AEC.
windowWidth:=80
windowHeight:=23
ASCIIofSpace<=" \0\0\0" ;As integer. We know we are dealing with a...
ASCIIofNewLine<="\n\0\0\0" ;32-bit little-endian machine.
ASCIIofStar<="*\0\0\0"
i:=0
While i<windowWidth*windowHeight ;First, fill the window with spaces and newlines.
    If mod(i,windowWidth)=windowWidth-1
        AsmStart
            .intel_syntax noprefix
            fild dword ptr ASCIIofSpace #Not need for a new line, DOS will do that automatically.
            fstp dword ptr currentSign
            .att_syntax
        AsmEnd
    Else
        AsmStart
            .intel_syntax noprefix
            fild dword ptr ASCIIofSpace
            fstp dword ptr currentSign
            fld dword ptr currentSign
            fstp dword ptr ASCIIofSpaceAsFloat32
            .att_syntax
        AsmEnd
    EndIf
    output[i]:=currentSign
    i:=i+1
EndWhile
AsmStart
.intel_syntax noprefix
.ifdef debugForDOS
    mov dl,'e'
    mov ax,0x200
    int 0x21
.endif
.att_syntax
AsmEnd
centerX:=windowWidth/2-mod(windowWidth/2,1)
centerY:=windowHeight/2-mod(windowHeight/2,1)
clockRadius:=(centerX<centerY)?(centerX):(centerY)-1
i:=0
While i<windowWidth*windowHeight ;Next, draw the circle which represents the clock.
    y:=i/windowWidth-mod(i/windowWidth,1) ;When I didn't put "floor" into my programming language...
    x:=mod(i,windowWidth)
    distance:=sqrt((x-centerX)*(x-centerX)+(y-centerY)*(y-centerY)) ;Pythagorean Theorem.
    If abs(distance-clockRadius)<3/4
        AsmStart
            .intel_syntax noprefix
            fild dword ptr ASCIIofStar
            fstp dword ptr currentSign
            .att_syntax
        AsmEnd
        output[i]:=currentSign
    EndIf
    i:=i+1
EndWhile
AsmStart
.intel_syntax noprefix
.ifdef debugForDOS
    mov dl,'l'
    mov ax,0x200
    int 0x21
.endif
.att_syntax
AsmEnd
AsmStart
    .intel_syntax noprefix
    jmp ASCIIofDigitsAsInt32Array$
    ASCIIofDigitsAsInt32Array:
    .macro writeDigits startingWith=0
        .byte '0'+\startingWith,0,0,0 #".byte" is to GNU Assembler about the same as "db" is to FlatAssembler.
        .if \startingWith < 9
            writeDigits \startingWith+1
        .endif
    .endm
    writeDigits #The goal is to make Assembler output the ASCII of "0\0\0\01\0\0\02\0\0\0...9\0\0\0" inside the executable (if the instruction pointer points to it, it will, of course, be an invalid instruction).
    ASCIIofDigitsAsInt32Array$:
    .att_syntax
AsmEnd
;Label of "12"...
AsmStart
    .intel_syntax noprefix
    fild dword ptr [ASCIIofDigitsAsInt32Array+1*4] #The ASCII of '1'.
    fstp dword ptr currentSign
    .att_syntax
AsmEnd
output[(centerY-clockRadius+1)*windowWidth+centerX]:=currentSign
AsmStart
    .intel_syntax noprefix
    fild dword ptr [ASCIIofDigitsAsInt32Array+2*4] #The ASCII of '2'.
    fstp dword ptr currentSign
    .att_syntax
AsmEnd
output[(centerY-clockRadius+1)*windowWidth+centerX+1]:=currentSign
AsmStart
    .intel_syntax noprefix
    fild dword ptr [ASCIIofDigitsAsInt32Array+6*4] #The ASCII of '6'.
    fstp dword ptr currentSign
    .att_syntax
AsmEnd
output[(centerY+clockRadius-1)*windowWidth+centerX]:=currentSign
AsmStart
    .intel_syntax noprefix
    fild dword ptr [ASCIIofDigitsAsInt32Array+3*4] #The ASCII of '3'.
    fstp dword ptr currentSign
    .att_syntax
AsmEnd
output[centerY*windowWidth+centerX+clockRadius-1]:=currentSign
AsmStart
    .intel_syntax noprefix
    fild dword ptr [ASCIIofDigitsAsInt32Array+9*4] #The ASCII of '9'.
    fstp dword ptr currentSign
    .att_syntax
AsmEnd
output[centerY*windowWidth+centerX-clockRadius+1]:=currentSign
AsmStart
    .intel_syntax noprefix
    fild dword ptr [ASCIIofDigitsAsInt32Array+1*4] #The ASCII of '1'.
    fstp dword ptr currentSign
    .att_syntax
AsmEnd
y:=centerY-(clockRadius-1)*cos(360/12)
y:=y-mod(y,1)
output[y*windowWidth+centerX+sin(360/12)*(clockRadius-1)]:=currentSign
AsmStart
    .intel_syntax noprefix
    fild dword ptr [ASCIIofDigitsAsInt32Array+2*4] #The ASCII of '2'.
    fstp dword ptr currentSign
    .att_syntax
AsmEnd
y:=centerY-(clockRadius-1.5)*cos(2*360/12)
y:=y-mod(y,1)
output[y*windowWidth+centerX+sin(2*360/12)*(clockRadius-1.5)]:=currentSign
AsmStart
    .intel_syntax noprefix
    fild dword ptr [ASCIIofDigitsAsInt32Array+4*4] #The ASCII of '4'.
    fstp dword ptr currentSign
    .att_syntax
AsmEnd
y:=centerY-(clockRadius-1)*cos(4*360/12)
y:=y-mod(y,1)
output[y*windowWidth+centerX+sin(4*360/12)*(clockRadius-1)]:=currentSign
AsmStart
    .intel_syntax noprefix
    fild dword ptr [ASCIIofDigitsAsInt32Array+5*4] #The ASCII of '5'.
    fstp dword ptr currentSign
    .att_syntax
AsmEnd
y:=centerY-(clockRadius-1)*cos(5*360/12)
y:=y-mod(y,1)
output[y*windowWidth+centerX+sin(5*360/12)*(clockRadius-1)]:=currentSign
AsmStart
    .intel_syntax noprefix
    fild dword ptr [ASCIIofDigitsAsInt32Array+7*4] #The ASCII of '7'.
    fstp dword ptr currentSign
    .att_syntax
AsmEnd
y:=centerY-(clockRadius-1)*cos(7*360/12)
y:=y-mod(y,1)
output[y*windowWidth+centerX+sin(7*360/12)*(clockRadius-1)]:=currentSign
AsmStart
    .intel_syntax noprefix
    fild dword ptr [ASCIIofDigitsAsInt32Array+8*4] #The ASCII of '8'.
    fstp dword ptr currentSign
    .att_syntax
AsmEnd
y:=centerY-(clockRadius-1)*cos(8*360/12)
y:=y-mod(y,1)
output[y*windowWidth+centerX+sin(8*360/12)*(clockRadius-1)]:=currentSign
;Label "10"...
AsmStart
    .intel_syntax noprefix
    fild dword ptr [ASCIIofDigitsAsInt32Array+1*4] #The ASCII of '1'.
    fstp dword ptr currentSign
    .att_syntax
AsmEnd
y:=centerY-(clockRadius-1.5)*cos(10*360/12)
y:=y-mod(y,1)
output[y*windowWidth+centerX+sin(10*360/12)*(clockRadius-1.5)]:=currentSign
AsmStart
    .intel_syntax noprefix
    fild dword ptr [ASCIIofDigitsAsInt32Array+0*4] #The ASCII of '0'.
    fstp dword ptr currentSign
    .att_syntax
AsmEnd
y:=centerY-(clockRadius-1.5)*cos(10*360/12)
y:=y-mod(y,1)
output[y*windowWidth+centerX+sin(10*360/12)*(clockRadius-1.5)+1]:=currentSign
;Label "11"...
AsmStart
    .intel_syntax noprefix
    fild dword ptr [ASCIIofDigitsAsInt32Array+1*4] #The ASCII of '1'.
    fstp dword ptr currentSign
    .att_syntax
AsmEnd
y:=centerY-(clockRadius-1.5)*cos(11*360/12)
y:=y-mod(y,1)
output[y*windowWidth+centerX+sin(11*360/12)*(clockRadius-1.5)]:=currentSign
AsmStart
    .intel_syntax noprefix
    fild dword ptr [ASCIIofDigitsAsInt32Array+1*4] #The ASCII of '1'.
    fstp dword ptr currentSign
    .att_syntax
AsmEnd
y:=centerY-(clockRadius-1.5)*cos(11*360/12)
y:=y-mod(y,1)
output[y*windowWidth+centerX+sin(11*360/12)*(clockRadius-1.5)+1] := currentSign
AsmStart
.intel_syntax noprefix
.ifdef debugForDOS
    mov dl,'o'
    mov ax,0x200
    int 0x21
.endif
.att_syntax
AsmEnd
j:=0
While j<3
    If j=0
        angle:=(mod(hour+minute/60,12))*(360/12)
    ElseIf j=1
        angle:=minute*(360/60)
    Else
        angle:=second*(360/60)
    EndIf
    endOfTheHandX:=centerX+sin(angle)*clockRadius/(j=0?2:j=1?3/2:4/3) ;Hour hand will be the shortest, and the hand that shows the seconds will be the longest.
    endOfTheHandY:=centerY-cos(angle)*clockRadius/(j=0?2:j=1?3/2:4/3)
    coefficientOfTheDirection:=(endOfTheHandY-centerY)/(endOfTheHandX-centerX)
    debugString <= "Drawing line between (%d,%d) and (%d,%d).\n\0"
    AsmStart
        .intel_syntax noprefix
        .ifdef DEBUG #Conditional assembly, this will only be assembled if you tell GNU Assembler (by modifying the file or using command line) that you want to enable debugging.
            fld dword ptr endOfTheHandY
            fistp dword ptr result
            push dword ptr result #This (pushing a "dword" onto the system stack) breaks the compatibility with 64-bit Linux (but you can still enable it by disabling debugging)!
            fld dword ptr endOfTheHandX
            fistp dword ptr result
            push dword ptr result
            fld dword ptr centerY
            fistp dword ptr result
            push dword ptr result
            fld dword ptr centerX
            fistp dword ptr result
            push dword ptr result
            lea ebx,debugString
            push ebx
            call printf #I hope this goes without saying, but, unless you link with a C library, this won't work under DOS.
        .endif #End of the conditional assembly.
        .att_syntax
    AsmEnd
    i:=0
    While i<windowWidth*windowHeight
        lowerBoundX:=(endOfTheHandX<centerX)?(endOfTheHandX):(centerX)
        upperBoundX:=(endOfTheHandX>centerX)?(endOfTheHandX):(centerX)
        lowerBoundY:=(endOfTheHandY<centerY)?(endOfTheHandY):(centerY)
        upperBoundY:=(endOfTheHandY>centerY)?(endOfTheHandY):(centerY)
        y:=i/windowWidth-mod(i/windowWidth,1)
        x:=mod(i,windowWidth)
        isXWithinBounds:=(x>lowerBoundX | x=lowerBoundX) & (x<upperBoundX | x=upperBoundX) ;Damn... Now I understand why almost every programming language supports the "<=" and ">=" operators, no matter how much harder they make the language to tokenize.
        isYWithinBounds:=(y>lowerBoundY | y=lowerBoundY) & (y<upperBoundY | y=upperBoundY)
        If isXWithinBounds=1 & isYWithinBounds=1
            expectedY:=(x-centerX)*coefficientOfTheDirection+centerY
            expectedX:=(y-centerY)*(1/coefficientOfTheDirection)+centerX
            debugString1 <= "The point (%d,%d) is within bounds, expectedY is %d and expectedX is %d.\n\0"
            AsmStart
                .intel_syntax noprefix
                .ifdef DEBUG
                    fld dword ptr expectedX
                    fistp dword ptr result
                    push dword ptr result
                    fld dword ptr expectedY
                    fistp dword ptr result
                    push dword ptr result
                    fld dword ptr y
                    fistp dword ptr result
                    push dword ptr result
                    fld dword ptr x
                    fistp dword ptr result
                    push dword ptr result
                    lea ebx,debugString1
                    push ebx
                    call printf
                .endif
                .att_syntax
            AsmEnd
            ASCIIofLetterH<="h\0\0\0"
            ASCIIofLetterM<="m\0\0\0"
            ASCIIofLetterS<="s\0\0\0"
            If j=0
                AsmStart
                    .intel_syntax noprefix
                    fild dword ptr ASCIIofLetterH
                    fstp dword ptr currentSign
                    .att_syntax
                AsmEnd
            ElseIf j=1
                AsmStart
                    .intel_syntax noprefix
                    fild dword ptr ASCIIofLetterM
                    fstp dword ptr currentSign
                    .att_syntax
                AsmEnd
            Else
                AsmStart
                    .intel_syntax noprefix
                    fild dword ptr ASCIIofLetterS
                    fstp dword ptr currentSign
                    .att_syntax
                AsmEnd
            EndIf
            If (upperBoundX=lowerBoundX | upperBoundY=lowerBoundY) & output[i]=ASCIIofSpaceAsFloat32
                output[i]:=currentSign
            EndIf
            If (abs(expectedY-y)<3/4 | abs(expectedX-x)<3/4) & output[i]=ASCIIofSpaceAsFloat32
                output[i]:=currentSign
            EndIf
        EndIf
        i:=i+1
    EndWhile
    j:=j+1
EndWhile
AsmStart
.intel_syntax noprefix
.ifdef debugForDOS
    mov dl,' '
    mov ax,0x200
    int 0x21
.endif
.att_syntax
AsmEnd
;Draw some ornament...
ASCIIofLetterX<="x\0\0\0"
AsmStart
    .intel_syntax noprefix
    fild dword ptr ASCIIofLetterX
    fstp dword ptr currentSign
    .att_syntax
AsmEnd
i:=0
AsmStart
.intel_syntax noprefix
.ifdef debugForDOS
    mov dl,'w'
    mov ax,0x200
    int 0x21
.endif
.att_syntax
AsmEnd
While i<windowWidth*windowHeight
    y:=i/windowWidth-mod(i/windowWidth,1)
    x:=mod(i,windowWidth)
    If abs(windowHeight-2*ln(1+abs((x-centerX)/2))-y)<1-abs(x-centerX)/(centerX*95/112) & x>1/2*centerX & x<3/2*centerX & output[i]=ASCIIofSpaceAsFloat32 ;The logarithmic curve looks somewhat like a lemma of a flower.
        output[i]:=currentSign
    EndIf
    i:=i+1
EndWhile
AsmStart
.intel_syntax noprefix
.ifdef debugForDOS
    mov dl,'o'
    mov ax,0x200
    int 0x21
.endif
.att_syntax
AsmEnd
AsmStart
    .intel_syntax noprefix
    fild dword ptr ASCIIofLetterX
    fstp dword ptr currentSign
    .att_syntax
AsmEnd
;Let's try to make it look like the bottom of the lemma isn't floating in the air.
j:=0
While j<3
    i:=windowWidth*(windowHeight-1) ;So, move to the beginning of the last line.
    While i<windowWidth*windowHeight
        If j<2 & (output[i-windowWidth]=currentSign & (output[i+1]=currentSign | output[i-1]=currentSign))
            output[i]:=currentSign
        ElseIf j=2 & (output[i+1]=ASCIIofSpaceAsFloat32 & output[i-windowWidth]=currentSign)
            output[i]:=ASCIIofSpaceAsFloat32
        EndIf
        i:=i+1
    EndWhile
    j:=j+1
EndWhile
AsmStart
.intel_syntax noprefix
.ifdef debugForDOS
    mov dl,'r'
    mov ax,0x200
    int 0x21
.endif
.att_syntax
AsmEnd
;Let's make a digital clock in the corner...
AsmStart
    .intel_syntax noprefix
    fild dword ptr ASCIIofDigitsAsInt32Array #So, load "0\0\0\0" (the first 32 bits of the array "ASCIIofDigitsAsInt32Array") into the st0 register and convert it to Float32.
    fstp dword ptr ASCIIofDigit0AsFloat32
    .att_syntax
AsmEnd
AsmStart
.intel_syntax noprefix
.ifdef debugForDOS
    mov dl,'l'
    mov ax,0x200
    int 0x21
.endif
.att_syntax
AsmEnd
ASCIIofColon<=":\0\0\0"
AsmStart
    .intel_syntax
    fild dword ptr ASCIIofColon
    fstp dword ptr ASCIIofColonAsFloat32
    .att_syntax
AsmEnd
output[windowWidth*windowHeight-2]:=ASCIIofDigit0AsFloat32+mod(second,10)
output[windowWidth*windowHeight-3]:=ASCIIofDigit0AsFloat32+second/10-mod(second/10,1)
output[windowWidth*windowHeight-4]:=ASCIIofColonAsFloat32
output[windowWidth*windowHeight-5]:=ASCIIofDigit0AsFloat32+mod(minute,10)
output[windowWidth*windowHeight-6]:=ASCIIofDigit0AsFloat32+minute/10-mod(minute/10,1)
output[windowWidth*windowHeight-7]:=ASCIIofColonAsFloat32
output[windowWidth*windowHeight-8]:=ASCIIofDigit0AsFloat32+mod(hour,10)
output[windowWidth*windowHeight-9]:=ASCIIofDigit0AsFloat32+hour/10-mod(hour/10,1)
AsmStart
.intel_syntax noprefix
.ifdef debugForDOS
    mov dl,'d'
    mov ax,0x200
    int 0x21
.endif
.att_syntax
AsmEnd
signature<="Analog Clock for DOS\nMade in AEC by\nTeo Samarzija\0"
currentSign:=signature[0]
i:=windowWidth*(windowHeight-3)
j:=0
While not(currentSign=0) ;That is, as long as it's not the '\0' sign.
    AsmStart
        .intel_syntax noprefix
        fld dword ptr j
        fistp dword ptr result
        mov ebx, dword ptr result
        movzx eax, byte ptr [signature+ebx] #I hope it goes without saying something like this (using post-Pentium instructions in inline assembly) won't work on a machine with an archaic processor. I am writing this program for a machine with a modern processor which happens to run DOS.
        mov dword ptr result, eax
        fild dword ptr result
        fstp dword ptr currentSign
        fild dword ptr ASCIIofNewLine
        fstp dword ptr ASCIIofNewLineAsFloat32
        .att_syntax
    AsmEnd
    If currentSign=ASCIIofNewLineAsFloat32
        i:=(i/windowWidth-mod(i/windowWidth,1)+1)*windowWidth
    ElseIf not(currentSign=0)
        output[i]:=currentSign
        i:=i+1
    Else
        output[i]:=ASCIIofSpaceAsFloat32
    EndIf
    j:=j+1
EndWhile
AsmStart
.intel_syntax noprefix
.ifdef debugForDOS
    mov dl,'!'
    mov ax,0x200
    int 0x21
.endif
.att_syntax
AsmEnd
AsmStart ;And this is, according to GCC 9.3.0, how you convert a Float32Array with ASCII codes and print it under DOS.
# 0 "" 2
/NO_APP
    movl    $0, -4(%ebp)
    jmp L3
L4:
    movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
    flds    output(,%eax,4)
    fnstcw  -18(%ebp)
    movw    -18(%ebp), %ax
    orb $12, %ah
    movw    %ax, -20(%ebp)
    fldcw   -20(%ebp)
    fistps  -22(%ebp)
    fldcw   -18(%ebp)
    movb    -22(%ebp), %al
    movsbl  %al, %eax
    pushl   %eax
    call    _putchar
    addl    $4, %esp
    incl    -4(%ebp)
L3:
    cmpl    $1839, -4(%ebp)
    jle L4
/APP
# 21 "analogClock.c" 1
    .intel_syntax noprefix
mov al,0 #And I hope this also goes without saying, but when there is...
mov ah,0x4C #...no C library, returning 0 from "main" crashes your program...
int 0x21 #...and you need to use OS-specific code to end it properly.
.att_syntax

# 0 "" 2
/NO_APP
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
LFE1:
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 9.3.0"
AsmEnd
```

The executable is available in this [ZIP-archive](https://github.com/FlatAssembler/ArithmeticExpressionCompiler/raw/master/ArithmeticExpressionCompiler.zip).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216939/discussion-on-question-by-flatassembler-ntvdm-system-error-4001h-when-running-a).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that NTVDM (NT Virtual DOS Machine) handles both 16-bit Windows applications and 16/32-bit DOS applications, and is a feature exclusive to the 32-bit (x86) version of Windows not 64-bit (x64).

I found this topic by searching 4001h error via. Google and for me I was able to run my DOS application by launching it via start> run > **command.com** and then running the EXE as opposed to using **CMD** or running direct.

Again, this is going to work on the 32-bit version of Windows only. 64-bit version of Windows does not have a *command.com* command for this to be possible.

Answer (score 5):

To me that error occured when trying to start a 16bit application (in a 32-bit version of Windows). More precise: I use a shortcut to a batch file and in there that application is called.

Solution in my case was to activate "**use legacy console**". This option can be found in `properties -> options` of that shortcut.

I'm aware, that this is maybe not the answer to the original question (I didn't test it). It may be helpful for those people, who came here searching the 4001h error. This solution is in corresponding cases probably a bit easier to achieve, than that one suggested by Member.